# How to pass variables to an included file

Tags: php, url, include

I include my file from domain to another domain in different servers 
It works but the problem I can't pass variables to my included file

I Mean like

```
included.php


$dbh= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=login', 'example', 'example');

$sql = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email = ? AND Password = ?');
$sql->execute(array($Email,$Password));
$count = $sql->rowCount();

if($count = 0) {
   echo 'hi';
}else{
   echo 'Wrong email or password';
}
```

`main.php`

```
$Email = 'example@example.com';
$Password = 'example';
include('http://example.com/included.php');
```

Comment: When you include from an external source like this, the remote server will execute the code and output the rendered response.  You are essentially including the same as you would see in a browser on that url, and not the code as you are expecting.

Comment: what should i do

Comment: including php remotely like this isn't safe. you would have to expose your code.  I'd suggest you rethink your method.  Why are you wanting to include code from an external source?  From the code you've provided it looks like you are trying to create an API. Have a read of this article (found with a quick google search) https://medium.freecodecamp.org/what-is-an-api-in-english-please-b880a3214a82

Comment: i have a hosting company and i want to add a php programming service so i don't want from my clients to expose the scripts so i want to create a folder for each one who had order a php programming in another server i mean another domain name which i have so that domain is only for the php programming orders it's safe the folders name is hashed everything is secure but the problem is the included file